# SQLITE_ERROR: near "OUTPUT": syntax error

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to get the ID of my new row inserted into my database during the insertion with `OUTPUT`. However, I'm getting this error:

```
SQLITE_ERROR: near "OUTPUT": syntax error
```

Here is the block of code that involves the `INSERT`:

```
global.db.all(
    `INSERT INTO articles(creation_date, publish_date, last_modified_date, title, subtitle, article_text, likes, author_id, published)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*
    VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`,
    newValues,
    function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            next(err); //send the error on to the error handler
        } else {
            res.json({message: "Saved", newRow: rows});
        }
    }
);
```

How do I get what I need with this `OUTPUT`? I've been trying out the examples others have provided but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not support the `OUTPUT` clause.

Instead, you should use [`RETURNING`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html):

```
INSERT INTO articles(creation_date, publish_date, last_modified_date, title, subtitle, article_text, likes, author_id, published)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
RETURNING *;
```

Also, if you want the columns `creation_date`, `publish_date` and `last_modified_date` to have the current timestamp as the default value it is simpler to define it in the table's `CREATE TABLE` statement, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE articles(
  .................................................
  creation_date TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  publish_date TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  last_modified_date TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  .................................................
);
```

and then the `INSERT` statement can be simplified to:

```
INSERT INTO articles(title, subtitle, article_text, likes, author_id, published)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
RETURNING *;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zwLPpOyS).